# Data transfer of added items between SAP ERP and SAP CRM

Tags: abap, sap-crm

Is there a SAP standard function module that transfers data of new items from ERP to CRM system?

Comment: Please add more details to your question, as explained in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To say, it's a little short, currently.

Answer (score 2):

It depends of what kind of items you wanna replicate:

1. For business-partners there are standard functions which [are adjustable from SPRO](https://help.sap.com/doc/7d71d9b30da14c5492e69cedf800be43/3.6/en-US/58dac53393d24e73a4044781c5d33a75.html)
2. For vendor data you can utilize [FSSC_BP_REPLICATION](https://www.stechno.net/sap-programs.html?id=FSSC_BP_REPLICATION) or [CRM_VENMAP_TO_CRMM_BUT_VENDNO](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/CRM/Replication+of+Vendor+Master+Data) reports
3. Order replication is triggered [automatically](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/CRM/How+is+the+sales+order+data+replicated+from+CRM+to+ECC) and you do not have to do anything, just to ensure the BAdI `CHANGE_BEFORE_UPDATE` is active

Check also the most common problems that are faced during distribution and their solutions: [TIPS to check the distribution of documents between CRM and ECC](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/CRM/TIPS+to+check+the+distribution+of+documents+between+CRM+and+ECC)

Manual ERP->CRM tables replication is not recommended by SAP, however there are also special tools for this. For example, SAP Data Services and SLT:

1. https://www.guru99.com/sap-ds-sap-data-services-in-sap-hana.html
2. https://blogs.sap.com/2018/10/30/slt-configuration-for-data-replication-from-s4hana-fashion-to-sap-car-system/
3. https://blogs.sap.com/2015/05/15/transformation-capabilities-of-sap-slt-vs-data-services/

Comment: Thank you for the information. I need to pass the values of the custom fields from standard table ERP to CRM.

Comment: Then SLT is your choice

Comment: It seems that SLT is not applicable for S4d to CRD system.

Comment: What is c4d and crd?

Comment: S4D client is for ERP system and CRD is for CRM system.

Comment: SLT supports any type of ABAP-based system, that supports RFC, and even pure DB-backends (Oracle, MSSQL). See p.9 [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/adacd9e3c19b42e29ec6cf6a22123668/3.0.01/en-US/Installation_Guide_SLT_for_ABAP_DMIS_2018_SP01.pdf).